# Exchange 2010 SP1 - View size of "Deleted Items" per user

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I'm looking for a quick way to obtain a per-user accounting of the size of the **"Deleted Items"** folder on an Exchange 2010 SP1 system. This is a recent migration, and I'm just trying to get an overview/baseline before implementing policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get the deleted item size for all users, sort it and throw it in a table for you:

> Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | sort TotalDeletedItemSize | ft DisplayName,TotalDeletedItemSize

and if you want to export to csv you need to change the "ft" to "Select-Object"

> Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | sort TotalDeletedItemSize | Select-object DisplayName,TotalDeletedItemSize | export-csv filePath.csv

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Get-Mailbox -database "DATABASENAME" -resultsize unlimited | 
    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics | 
    ? {$_.FolderPath -eq "/Deleted Items"} | 
    Select Identity, FolderAndSubFolderSize | 
    Sort-Object FolderAndSubFolderSize -Descending | 
    Export-CSV "FILEPATH.csv"
```

It was exactly what I needed and I hope it might help someone else along the way.